# Framework7: Default url to a different view is not working

Tags: javascript, html, ios, cordova, html-framework-7

As we can see in the views page of documents in Framework7.

> Default View URL
>
> If you think that for some reason Framework7 detects wrong default
>   View URL (which is used for navigation history), or if you want to
>   have different default View URL, you can specify it using data-url
>   attribute on View element or using url parameter when you initialze
>   View:

```
<div class="view" data-url="index2.html">
```

If I do as the doc suggests, for example, in the app which accompany the framework7 package, single view app, laying under /dist/index.html, if I do something like:

```
<div class="view view-main" data-url='about.html'>
```

But when i open index.html, the main view is not directing to about.html.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

It does not work like that. I think you want to load the about.html as default in the main view. You can do this something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    ...    
</head>
<body>
    ....
    <div class="views">
        <div class="view view-main"></div>
    </div>
    ...
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/framework7.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/my-app.js"></script>    
    ...

    <script>
        mainView.router.loadPage('about.html');
    </script>   

</body>
</html>
```